# Will a monitor work if I make a VGA cable with common return and ground?

Tags: display, rgb, vga

This has been bugging me for a while but will a monitor unit work if I make common ground for returns for RGB and the ground?

A bit scared to test it on my monitor.

Comment: You can connect together all the GND pins. If you have a ohmmeter you will see that they are already connected both on the PC and the display. Now, if you are making a cable, image quality may suffer if the colours and synchros are not wired in separate controlled impedance twisted or coaxial wires.

Comment: So if I short them, they keep displaying right?

Comment: I have done this couple years ago. Worked fine, no issues. What you achieve may vary due to interferences... anyway, you should not be afraid to test it.

Comment: Sure, it may have some ghosting. But why would you want to do this?

Comment: I'm trying to build a 2 CPU-single Monitor relay kind of stuff. It'll basically switch displays of the two cpus to the same monitor and not run them simultaneously. So I thought that if flipping just the ground connections between the two CPUs I can achieve that. Any ideas?

Comment: Bad idea. You intend to leave the signal lines connected and switch the grounds. Even if the grounds aren't connected alternatively via mains ground, USB or something else there will be enough capacitance to ground to drive the signals crazy.

Comment: Then how would you suggest to flip over all the lines of one wire to a different wire using just a single switch?

Comment: Use a three pole switch and switch the signal lines.

Comment: @AniruddhaBera You can't do this with a single switch. All of the signals (R, G, B, Hsync, Vsync, and the EDID pins) need to be switched for correct behavior.

Comment: @duskwuff so separate switches for all the lines. Copy that.